# How to minify HTML generated by draftjs?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, draftjs, react-draft-wysiwyg

I am using `react-draft-wysiwyg` to create content on a React web app and `react-native-webview` to display the content on React Native.

My plan is to convert the draftjs content to HTML so I can store it directly in the database and display it using `react-native-webview`. I am using the `draftjs-to-html` package for the conversion.

```
draftToHtml(convertToRaw(editorState.getCurrentContent()))
```

I noticed that the output generated is not minified and I am concerned about DB size. Is it possible to minify the output so I can save space ? If so how ?

> I am aware that the `RawDraftContentState` format is very well suited to save data in DB. However I am concerned about packages which render them on React Native as most of the repos are updated more than a year ago.

> Please enlighten me if there are alternative approaches/packages on how this can be done. The objective is to create a WYSIWYG editor on the React web app and it should render it on React Native

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `replace` string function with `regex` gives a minified HTML.

```
const nonMinifiedHTML  = draftToHtml(convertToRaw(editorState.getCurrentContent()));
const minifiedHTML = nonMinifiedHTML.replace( /[\r\n]+/gm, "" );
```